# How do wallets know that address is not duplicated if I'm going to make one?

Tags: wallet, address-generation

Let's assume that I'm going to make a wallet through Electrum that has some Bitcoin address.

So then, How Electrum do know that is not duplicated(Already owned by another person)?

Are we just relying on big numbers(2^160)? or Does Bitcoin system has some function to prevent duplicate?

Thank you for listening my question. No offense! Just curious about the function or how it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are we just relying on big numbers(2^160)?

Yes

> or Does Bitcoin system has some function to prevent duplicate?

No